# Variable .htaccess Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bit of trouble with mod_rewrite. Thanks for any help.

I'm trying to change this starting URL:

```
http://www.example.com/profile.php?u=72
```

into this URL I want to display:

```
http://www.example.com/username
```

where `username` is the username of user #72, as stored in a MySQL database. What steps should I take to make this happen for all users?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself yet? Done any research?

Comment: I know basic mod_rewrite stuff, but I don't how to use it to use information from a database, or even if this is the right way to do it. and yes, of course I've done research, but I can't find anything on this. Or I'm just really dumb. Thanks for the downvote, cheers.

Comment: @Eric I didn't down vote your question! Your question just appeared to be "give me teh codez". Can you show us what you have tried and didn't work? Also you're clearly not dumb :)

Comment: Also I dont know if you've seen this or not but it's a great resource http://forum.modrewrite.com/

Comment: @sabre I appreciate it. I apparently was thinking about the problem the wrong way. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure username is unique in your database - check case sensitivity too.
2. Replace all old urls in your application pointing to the former url to the one using username.
3. On your user detail page, select by username instead of id.

If you have any problems, I'm happy to help with specific questions.

Comment: So basically replace the old url to `http://www.example.com/profile.php?u=username` and then mod_rewrite that. Very cool, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're thinking about it backwards - instead think about how you would translate `example.com/username` into a URL like `example.com/profile.php?name=username`, which your PHP can then work with. Usually when you use mod_rewrite, you change the links in your site to link to clean URLs, and use mod_rewrite to make it understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Your mod_rewrite does not use information from a database, you use it to load another page while showing the url you want.

You cannot use it exactly like you want, if the url does not contain the user ID, you cannot redirect to `http://www.example.com/profile.php?u=72`. However you can redirect to `http://www.example.com/profile.php?username=username` and in `profile.php` lookup the correct user based on the username instead of the id.